# Getting selection on a single row in ui-grid when modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true and multiSelect is true

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid on a page with

> modifierKeysToMultiSelect: true

and

> $scope.exampleGridOptions.multiSelect = true;

I am trying to get the selected row values if only a single row is selected from the grid.

I call the

> rowSelectionChangedBatch()

method and this is called only if more than one row is selected.

How do I get a row value if only one row is selected from the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call the method

> rowSelectionChanged()

along with

> rowSelectionChangedBatch()

to get a single row value.